# Override overview (old menu) button in Android

Tags: android

In my app I want that it is not possible to press the overview Button (the old menu button). I already overrided the `onBackPressed` button. But for the Overview button which shows all other Running apps it is not possible. Is there any other possibility (also with root rigths and system wide) to disable this button?
I also tried to edit some *.kl files in `/system/usr/keylayout` without success

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a late answer, but I've been looking for something similar and came across [this article](https://hackernoon.com/disable-android-home-back-and-active-apps-buttons-f7450dfeddcd). Maybe it is useful for someone else as well. The approach is rather simple.

You need to declare the following in the Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

Then in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
}
```

This is working for me.